# ListView height = 0?

Tags: android, listview

I can easily set the height of a row to 1 with

```
View.getLayoutParams().height = 1
```

But when I set it to 0, nothing happens

Is it possible somehow to set the height of a row in a ListView, to 0?

Comment: Are you looking to set it to 0 in order to hide it?

Comment: why do you want to do this? Are you trying top hide the row?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to hide a row in my ListView. This seems like the only way to do it for me.

Comment: what about `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it is not possible to do this using View.Gone but it is possible in another way:

Check my post it has the whole implementation: [ListView with ability to hide rows](http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2012/01/listview-with-ability-to-hide-rows.html)

**Enjoy**

Comment: It's a good implementation, but sadly it screws up the data in my App if I were to change the getCount() method in that way, but I will mark it as the accepted answer since others will probably be able to use your example.

Comment: why would it screw up your data? Can you explain?

Comment: It's just because I rely too heavily on the adapter when I communicate with the DB. I can do it, but it would result in a major rewrite.

Comment: @Rasive :( I think this will work no matter what. Just change the position of getView to the new Position and keep the old implementation. Every thing sums up to changing the position you work with in the function `getView()`

Comment: Yeah, you are right that I can solve it by just playing around with the position argument passed in getView(). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
View.setVisibility = GONE;
```

It depends if you want to hide the view or make it invisible. Depending on which you can use either GONE or INVISIBLE.

This is documented at [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

Comment: Yes, I have already done that, but that just leaves a blank row with the same height as the others.

Comment: Basically the problem is that if this is my list, when I use View.GONE, this happens -> |1|2| |4| Whereas 3 should be collapsed or gone, but it still takes up space. That is why I was trying to set the height to 0, but it might as well be something gone wrong with measuring the row, as I do all this in getView().

Answer (score 0):

Just try to make the row visibility to `View.GONE` and your item should disappear

Comment: as Graham Smith response, see In comment that in ListView setting View.GONE to item just make it blank whitout changing their height = blank row with same height

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide a ListView row you need to bind the adapter data again without that row in the data.